# how to obtain a webhook for a readthedocument

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm having trouble on importing a documentation from GitHub. readthedocs, gives me this error (I try to translate, it is in Italian)

"This repository has not set up a valid webhook, commits will not launch new builds of the project. See the integrations of your project for more information."

Can someone tell me what can I do? Or just where I can find some information about

Renato

Comment: Do I have to explain something other? If yes, what?

Comment: hplease help me. I'm unable to import GitHub repo from more days, and I've read much doc about it.
I'm sure this is a little thing that I cant see, but that block me from more days

Comment: reading the doc, I've found it (that I think could be my solution)
For Payload URL, use the URL of the integration on Read the Docs, found [on the integration detail page page] thhis last phrase is a link that should lead me to some addr pages.
But it does not work (it just bring me to the same page that come from. Where is this page where I can find the webhook URL?

Comment: I think I've finaly find what I was looking for:
https://hackernoon.com/71-seconds-to-build-your-free-custom-webhook-illustrated-step-by-step-7a09b9e240ba

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same myself and found a self-referencing link on the docs page.

I believe you go to readthedocs.org/dashboard, log in with your username and password for rtd, then go to Admin > Integrations to see the Payload URL. Then follow the instructions in https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webhooks.html.

For one of my projects, I go to this link for the Dashboard > Admin > Integrations page:
https://readthedocs.org/dashboard/rockthedocs-demo/integrations/40708/
On that page, the Payload URL looks like this:
readthedocs.org/api/v2/webhook/rockthedocs-demo/40708/

You can verify if the webhook is working at the bottom of the GitHub page under **Recent Deliveries**. If you see a `Response 200`, then the webhook is correctly configured.